# missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'JodaSetParameter.class'

Tags: scala, jodatime

I'm using this build.sbt

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0",
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "2.0.0",
    "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.187",
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34",
    "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.0" % "test",
    specs2 % Test
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.1.0",
    "com.github.tototoshi" %% "slick-joda-mapper" % "1.2.0",
    "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.7",
    "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.7"
)

resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

fork in run := true
```

and the following errors happens:

> missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file
>   'JodaSetParameter.class'.

What am I missing? Should I be using a different version of joda?

Comment: upgraded to latest version of joda time libraries and solved the issue